# Django Rest Framework nested serialization validators

Tags: django-rest-framework

Is there a way to bypass Django Rest Framework validators in nested serialization without overwriting the validators on the original serializers?

Example :

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username')


class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer()

    class Meta:
        model = models.Task
```

If I try to update or create a Task I'll get a unicity error, because DRF use the unique constraint on the username field of the User model.

The solution I have found is to overwrite the validators on the UserSerializer:

```
class UserSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ('username')
        extra_kwargs = {
            'username': {
                'validators': []
            }
```

Is there a way to bypass this validation without overwriting the validators directly in the UserSerializer? 
By overwriting this validator I have to rewrite every constraints that I defined on my model.

A solution like below would have been nice, since it would have allow to bypass the validators only in the TaskSerializer without overwriting the initial UserSerializer.

```
class TaskSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    owner = UserSerializer(validators=[])

    class Meta:
        model = models.Task
```